# Some webpages cannot be accessed from USB-thethered device but work fine on the iPhone

Tags: macos, ios, tethering

because my MacBook's WIFI peacefully transitioned to the eternal hunting grounds, I am forced to tether to an iPhone via USB to be able to access the interwebs for now.
For some, probably DNS-setting related, reason a number of websites cannot be contacted on the MacBook but work fine on the phone. The problem did not exist when connected via WIFI.
Does anyone know what I might have to look into? Special DNS settings on the MacBook? Any settings on iOS?

Thanks a lot